# How to interpret JMeter result while doing Database testing

Tags: database, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have recently started working with jMeter. And I was doing database stress testing for that. I have added the required drivers in the lib folder. And my jMeter is connected to database. And it works fine.

But the problem now I am facing is how to interpret those results. I just tested only one SQL which is doing `SELECT` on one table. Below is the screenshot of my various tabs in JMeter.

This below screenshot shows how many threads (10) I am running and Ramp up time.

[image]

This below screenshot shows me JDBC Connection Configuration settings, which I am not able to understand as well. It will be great if anyone can throw some thoughts on this what does it mean corresponding to number of threads I am running in my above picture.

[image]

This Below screenshot shows the result in a Summary report which I am again not able to interpret. What's the best way to interpret these results? Any thoughts on this will be of great help.

[image]

This Below screenshot shows the result which I am again not able to interpret. What's the best way to interpret these results? I was looking for how much time it is taking to execute that one single Select SQL. And this tab shows me lot of information but not sure how to interpret those. Any thoughts on this will be of great help.

[image]

Can anyone help me understanding these results? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of these:

- [Response Time Graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Time_Graph)
- [Aggregate Graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Graph)

Look also at jmeter-plugins project:

- http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/